# Identify the path in Graph traversing

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, janusgraph, dgraph, cayley

In the graph database, I want to know from which route I traverse

e.g.

Path-1. **a**-1-2-3-4-5-**b**

Path-2. **a**-1-2-7-4-5-**b**

In both the above examples, it traverses from **point a** to **point b** through different routes.
Here I want to identify from which route I reach to **point b**.

Comment: If you are using Gremlin can you please provide the query you have so far and if possible a little sample data. That will make it easier to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NODES` function to list the nodes in a path. There is also a `RELATIONSHIPS` function for listing the relationships.

For example, if this query finds the 2 paths in your question, it will return the nodes in each path:

```
MATCH path = (a:A)-[*]->(b:B)
RETURN NODES(path) AS nodesInPath
```